# Dualbooting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, uefi, bios

My question isn't actually about dual-booting them. I have a dual-boot set up and running perfectly. There is only one flaw I was looking for an answer to. Since I haven't had any success through others asking this and using their answers I'd figure I'd ask myself. Both OS's boot perfectly fine there are no errors. I do however have to boot through the BIOS everytime if I would like to switch OS's. While this isn't necessarily a problem, it is a huge nuisance to have to rapidly press delete everytime I would rather boot into Ubuntu than Windows. I'm not necessarily looking for a Graphical boot manager. More like the boot manager rEEfit that is used to assist in selecting which OS to boot into on MAC OSX. I have tried easyBCD, and it flat out just doesn't work, it'll boot into windows fine, but it gives me EFI errors if I select Ubuntu. Maybe I'm just using it wrong I don't know. If anyone can offer any help please do!

My dual-boot is Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Are your systems installed on the separate drives? What happens when you select `Windows 8` entry in GRUB menu?

Comment: When I boot my computer it by default boots into Windows 8. On boot up I have to hit Delete in order to access BIOS and manually select Ubuntu. When I boot Ubuntu of course the GRUB appears and I can select the normal Ubuntu boot. However if I select Windows from GRUB it says invalid EFI shell. If I boot into Windows using easyBCD and I make a Ubuntu boot option, I can select Windows and it boots just fine, but if I select Ubuntu it has an mbr error I believe. I'm trying to make things as simple as possible by not having to go into the BIOS every boot if I wish to switch OS's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First and foremost**

You have to make sure your EUFI is disabled at the BIOS. The EUFI stands for Unified Extensible Firmware Interface. To do that visit this [link](http://all4naija.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-disable-uefi-mode-in-windows-8.html)

**Second thing to do**

Download grub repair and run it and follow the on-screen instructions.

To do that visit this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

**On the final note**

You need to restart your system for changes to take effect.

Comment: Thank's so much! My computer now default boots into GRUB and I can successfully boot into either Windows 8 or Ubuntu from it!

Answer (score 1):

Windows will only boot with UEFI, so you need UEFI enabled. 
Some only boot Windows with secure boot on, others will boot UEFI both Windows & Ubuntu with secure boot off. Some also have a modified UEFI that only boots the Windows efi file.
The link to Boot-Repair will fix those issues. But you have to have both systems booting with UEFI either both UEFI or both UEFI secure boot. You cannot convert Windows to BIOS/CSM unless you have another licensed install and totally reinstall in BIOS with MBR partitioning.

Same link as posted before.
Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot.:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair